# Is there a way to make these closely-related types interoperable?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class for treating data stored elsewhere as a 2-D image.

```
template <typename Pixel>
class ImageWin {
   ...
};
```

It has iterators for read/write access to the underlying image and const_iterators for read-only access, and as you would expect, const methods return const iterators and non-const methods return non-const iterators.  If the `Pixel` type is const, then all of the iterators are const iterators.

This makes `ImageWin<const int>` and `const ImageWin<int>` very similar types.  They both have  the same set of iterators (const iterators).  Neither one can modify the underlying pixels.  The only difference is that `ImageWin<const int>` can be made to point somewhere else (i.e., where the window points to is mutable, but the pixels are not).

If I have a function that needs read access to the pixel data,  I would like to be able to declare something like:

```
void needs_read_only( const ImageWin<int>&  image );
```

The question is, is there any way to pass `ImageWin<const int>` into it?  I could certainly make it a template function, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible. I was thinking that I could make const `ImageWin<Pixel>` implicitly convertible to `ImageWin<const Pixel>`, but I actually want the reverse since a `const ImageWin` is more restrictive than an `ImageWin` of const pixels.  In general, I can't make `ImageWin<Pixel>` convertible to `ImageWin<const Pixel>` because that would violate the const-ness of the pixels if the `ImageWin<Pixel>` weren't const.

Are there any tricks I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: How about inheritance?

Comment: Would it be sensible to change the function to operate on iterators instead of the container?

Comment: `const ImageWin<T>` is not the same type as `ImageWin<const T>`. For your function it might not matter but they are not same type in general since the latter is allowed to change ImageWin state, while the former is not. Work with iterators as suggested by vhallac or make it template.

Comment: You can avoid using `const ImageWin<T>` and use `const ImageWin<const T>` instead.

Comment: I agree that I could use iterators.  I'm putting ImageWin in a library, though, and I would like to preserve the interface of passing const ImageWin<T>&, if possible.  I think I've come up with a solution, though.  I could define a conversion operator to const ImageWin< boost::remove_const<T>::type >.  From my reading it seems that if T is not const, then the conversion operator from ImageWin<T> to const ImageWin<T> would never be used, but if T were const, it would be exactly what I want.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply overload it ?

```
void needs_read_only( const ImageWin<Pixel>&  image ) /* const ??? */;

void needs_read_only( const ImageWin<const Pixel>&  image ) /* const ??? */;
```

Feel free to factor out the logic between two implementations. You can pass any kind of reference to these functions.

As a sidenote, if they are member functions, double-check if the `this` pointer should be const.